# How to fetch a single result from mysql using code igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Having trouble with Codeigniter. I am trying to fetch the value of a product from mysql. The mysql table contain a field called `cost_price`. I am trying to fetch the result of a single product using the product ID. Here is the code im using,

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id="$id"');
$row = $query->result();
echo $row['cost_price'];
```

But nothing is happening ! What is the problem with my code?

I tried some wrong code to check whether the database is responding or not, but it seems that the database is working fine. Can't understand why my query can't find any result !

Comment: echo out your $query, does it look normal ?

Comment: Frankly speaking i am not familiar with CI. i don't even know how this DB Query class work. I just find some answer in their DOC and used it. but not working !

Comment: The problem with your original query is that you put a variable reference ($id) inside a single-quoted phrase. PHP does not convert '$id' to the value. If you put variables inside a quoted phrase, use double quotes on the outside. For further clarity, wrap your variables in {braces}. For example: `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id={$id}");`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$row = $this->db->get_where('items', array('id' => $id))->row();
```

Or, if you just need the price:

```
$price = $this->db->select('cost_price')
                  ->get_where('items', array('id' => $id))
                  ->row()
                  ->cost_price;
```

EDIT

Your method was ok up to a point, look:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id="$id"');
$res = $query->result();  // this returns an object of all results
$row = $res[0];           // get the first row
```

<strike>`echo $row['cost_price'];`</strike> // we have an object, not an array, so we need:

```
echo $row->cost_price;
```

Alternatively, if you want an array, you can use `result_array()` instead of `result()`.

My way, `row()`, returns only the first row. It's also an object, and if you need an array, you can use `row_array()`.

I suggest you read more about all that [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Comment: No problem! :) Read the CI docs - they are quite good. And don't forget to select the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah, Have to wait 2 more min to accept the answer !

Comment: Great, I'll write you a little explanation till then.

Comment: Now its pretty clear to me. Thanks a lot again. You explained it better then official CI documents !